# Strange Behavior of ScheduledTask

Tags: scheduledtask

I have a background task that handles some simulations. It has worked fine for quite some time but all of a sudden it did not work at all. I traced it down to some strange behavior of ScheduledTask

```
In[1]:= Attributes[ScheduledTask]
Out[1]= {}

In[2]:= obj=SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[Print[DateString[]],{3,5}]]
During evaluation of In[2]:= Thu 10 Sep 2020 12:56:37
During evaluation of In[2]:= Thu 10 Sep 2020 12:56:37
During evaluation of In[2]:= Thu 10 Sep 2020 12:56:37
Out[2]= TaskObject[Task UUID: ab3631dd-10dd-4b52-88df-c12dda751f4f
Task environment: Session
Task type: Scheduled
**Evaluation expression: Null**
]

SetAttributes[ScheduledTask, HoldFirst]

In[4]:= obj = SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[Print[DateString[]], {3, 5}]]

Out[4]= TaskObject[<|
  TaskUUID -> adaf1093 - 6 ccc - 4 ccb - 927 f - b34e0832fac3, 
  TaskEnvironment -> Session, TaskType -> Scheduled, << 3 >>, 
  HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {Task, TaskUUID, TaskType, TaskStatus, 
    TaskEnvironment, HandlerFunctions, HandlerFunctionsKeys, 
    EventName, EvaluationExpression, << 4 >>, Rema << 11 >> nt, 
    NextScheduledTime, TotalRunCount, MessageOutput, PrintOutput}, 
  AutoRemove -> True|>]
```

Very strange that ScheduledTask does not have any attributes, not even Protected.
I have to manually set HoldFirst in order to get the expected behavior.
Any Idea what is going on?

I have rebooted the computer with no difference. The only change I can think of is that I updated windows 10.

Comment: Interesting that is is not `Protected`. It has `HoldAll` in 12.1.1.0 but no other attributes.

Comment: Very strange. Today I tried it on another computer and it has ```{HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected}```